# How to generate the JRE Sha25 from an oracle jre server version?

Tags: java, rsa-sha256

I need to generate the sha for the next URL:

https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u301-b09/d3c52aa6bfa54d3ca74e617f18309292/server-jre-8u301-linux-x64.tar.gz

Because I need the `oracle_jre_sha` param to run some jobs. I'm not pretty sure about this concept, it this topic related to the chef-nexus-repository-manager
https://github.com/sonatype/chef-nexus-repository-manager/blob/master/Jenkinsfile.

I found this topic: https://github.com/sous-chefs/java/issues/316, but not pretty sure how can I generate this sha from this JRE version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is a 32 hex characters.  32 x 4 is 128 bits.  The hashes that Oracle publishes (e.g. here https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u301checksum.html) are SHA256 and MD5 ... and none of them match that what is in that URL.

My guess is that Oracle are *deliberately* using UIDs in the URLs to make it hard for users to download a JRE or JDK without using an Oracle account and signifying that they have read and agree to the license terms.  It would be self-defeating for them to make it easy for users to work out what the UIDs are going to be.  With SHA512, they can make it effectively impossible, and I don't see why they *wouldn't* do that.

If this is problematic for you, my advice would be to download the installers that you need **by hand** and save a copy in your own **private** infrastructure.  Then set up your Chef cookbook to deploy Java from your private copy.  Note that this is the recommendation here:

- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java/versions/8.0.0

and this cookbook specifically supports this way of handling the problem.

Alternatively, use an alternative to Oracle Java that doesn't make scripted Java installation difficult.

Comment: Do you know how can I define the chef recipe  for this version? I'm not pretty sure how to achieve this. thanks!

Comment: I have added a link.  Please read it ... and follow it's recommendations.  That's all the advice I can give.